# Amplitude Embedding using Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, embedding

I saw that Pennylane proposed AmplitudeEmbedding in their modules to perform this task but I couldn't find one for Qiskit.

How to make amplitude embedding using qiskit ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work for you, it seems somewhat comparable https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.circuit.library.RawFeatureVector.html